# How to delete and why auto input to database?

Tags: php, sql-update

Could someone help me?
im making edit post with image in it, this code works but if i choose another image, the old one still inside my folder.

And second problem is if im not choose any image, the image name in database change. Its like i choose image but only the $randomnewedit being input.

```
if (isset ($_POST['submitedit'])){
$uploads_dir = '../images';
$randomedit   = time('YmdHis');
$randomnewedit = $randomedit."_";
$tipe_fileedit      = $_FILES['filefotoedit']['type'];
$tmp_fileedit       = $_FILES['filefotoedit']['tmp_name'];
$nama_fileedit      = $_FILES['filefotoedit']['name'];
$new_nama_fileedit  = $randomnewedit.$nama_fileedit;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_fileedit,"$uploads_dir/$new_nama_fileedit");

    $namabankedit=trim($_POST['namabankedit']);
    $cabangedit=trim($_POST['cabangedit']);
    $norekeningedit=trim($_POST['norekeningedit']);
    $namanasabahedit=trim($_POST['namanasabahedit']);

    $kueri = "UPDATE trans SET namabank='" . $namabankedit. "', cabang='" . $cabangedit. "', rekeningbank='" . $norekeningedit. "', namanasabah='" . $namanasabahedit. "', logobank='" . $new_nama_fileedit. "' WHERE idtrans='" . $idedit . "'";
    $hasil = mysql_query($kueri);
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=indexcuko.php?module=rekening'>";
}}}
```

And here's my edit form:

```
if (isset ($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act']:0){
if ($_GET['act'] == 'edit') {
$idedit = $_GET['id'];
$resultedit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans WHERE idtrans = $idedit;");
$rowedit = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultedit);
$titlenamabank = $rowedit['namabank'];
$titlecabang = $rowedit['cabang'];
$titlerekeningbank = $rowedit['rekeningbank'];
$titlenamanasabah = $rowedit['namanasabah'];
$titlelogobank = $rowedit['logobank'];
echo"
<h1>Edit Rekening</h1>
<form action='' method=\"post\" onreset=\"location.href=rekening.php\" name=\"form2\"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table class=\"tableb\">
    <tr>
    <td width=120 align=center>Nama Bank</td>
    <td align=center>:</td>
    <td width=120 align=center><input class=\"inputz\" name=\"namabankedit\" id=\"namabank\" type=\"text\" size=\"50\" value=\"$titlenamabank\" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width=120 align=center>Cabang</td>
    <td align=center>:</td>
    <td width=120 align=center><input class=\"inputz\" name=\"cabangedit\" id=\"cabang\" type=\"text\" size=\"50\" value=\"$titlecabang\" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width=120 align=center>No. Rekening</td>
    <td align=center>:</td>
    <td width=120 align=center><input class=\"inputz\" name=\"norekeningedit\" id=\"norekening\" type=\"text\" size=\"50\" value=\"$titlerekeningbank\" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width=120 align=center>Atas Nama</td>
    <td align=center>:</td>
    <td width=120 align=center><input class=\"inputz\" name=\"namanasabahedit\" id=\"namanasabah\" type=\"text\" size=\"50\" value=\"$titlenamanasabah\" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width=120 align=center>Logo Bank</td>
    <td align=center>:</td>
    <td width=120 align=center><input name=\"filefotoedit\" id=\"filefoto\" type=\"file\" value=\"$titlelogobank\" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=\"3\"><button class=\"buttonz\" name=\"submitedit\" type=\"submit\" onClick=\"return verify()\" value=\"save\">Simpan</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>";}}
```

sorry if saying it wrong, im not really good at english!

Comment: Warning: you are using deprecated mysql_* library

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should consider using prepared statements and parameterized queries for security purposes.

Comment: `if (isset ($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act']:0)` double condition, and not assigning anything. It should be $someVar = isset($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act'] : 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **unlink** the old file before get into upload or after using php inbuilt function.

```
unlink("filepath/filename");
```

For second problem: You need to check the file is exist or not based on that,

```
       $nama_fileedit      = $_FILES['filefotoedit']['name'];


    $new_nama_fileedit  = $randomnewedit.$nama_fileedit;


        $namabankedit=trim($_POST['namabankedit']);
        $cabangedit=trim($_POST['cabangedit']);
        $norekeningedit=trim($_POST['norekeningedit']);
        $namanasabahedit=trim($_POST['namanasabahedit']);

        if(isset($nama_fileedit){

             move_uploaded_file($tmp_fileedit,"$uploads_dir/$new_nama_fileedit");

             $kueri = "UPDATE trans SET namabank='" . $namabankedit. "', cabang='" . $cabangedit. "', rekeningbank='" . $norekeningedit. "', namanasabah='" . $namanasabahedit. "', logobank='" . $new_nama_fileedit. "' WHERE idtrans='" . $idedit . "'";

         }else{

              $kueri = "UPDATE trans SET namabank='" . $namabankedit. "', cabang='" . $cabangedit. "', rekeningbank='" . $norekeningedit. "', namanasabah='" . $namanasabahedit. "'  WHERE idtrans='" . $idedit . "'";
         }
        $hasil = mysql_query($kueri);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=indexcuko.php?module=rekening'>";
```

Comment: thanks alot, answer for second problem works great, um about first problem.
if i put `unlink("filepath/filename");` under `if(isset($nama_fileedit){` that you give me, how i give the unlink statement know what's name of old image file that i choose to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your **first** question:

In your code, variable $randomedit   = time('YmdHis');  is causing the problem. As it is using the current time, at any point of time you wont find the files with same unique name therefore there will be no question of over-writing the file. Also, you have not explicitly deleting the file using unlink() function.

Answer to your **second** question:

The image name in database changes because you are not checking whether the file is being uploaded. Check for $_FILES array whether it contains any values in it. If it contains values then only send the new filename to the update query else dont update the filename in database.

Hope this will help you.